PSA: it's now possible for moderators to undelete comments that weren't mod-deleted
I guess this is not a very new change, but I just discovered it very recently. It used to be the case that moderators could only undelete comments if they'd been deleted by moderators (including the Community bot), whereas self-deleted non-mod comments and comments deleted by user flags couldn't be undeleted without special CM intervention. Now, it seems that moderators can undelete any deleted comment. It's not easy to do so, and requires a different part of the mod functionality compared with undeletion of mod-deleted comments (which can be done very easily, directly from the post that was commented on).
Usually, undeletion of comments is a very rare thing to need doing. But specifically here on SFF, we have a recurring problem where OP comments confirming story-ID answers as correct (which are used as reason for duplicate closure according to our policy) are auto-deleted by well-meaning flaggers who think "Thanks, this is it" is a superfluous comment.
After recently discovering this "new" (ish) mod ability, I undeleted a couple of those story-ID confirmation comments which I happened to remember having seen deleted recently. But this is a problem going back years. If anyone happens to have a list of posts with such comments, or if anyone can think of a good way of searching to find such posts, feel free to post an answer here on this meta. If not, at least this meta post will stand as an FYI to the community that you can now flag in such cases for the important comment to be undeleted. (If anyone does have a list of hundreds of cases, posting it here is preferable to flagging them all, so as not to overwhelm the mod flag queue, please.)

Good, but wasn't it always possible for moderators to just post a new comment stating that this answer was confirmed by the original poster in a deleted comment, or even quoting the deleted comment? Was this ever done?

@user14111 Yes, that's what we had to do sometimes, but various problems: (1) not possible to reply to a deleted comment asking the OP to accept (especially when they logged in from a different account to confirm, so a comment on the question wouldn't notify them any more); (2) such comments from mods could also be auto-deleted with single flags, if they quoted the original comment; (3) it's just a much more indirect solution than simply undeleting the wrongly deleted comment.

This feature isn't new - it's existed for many years, at least since January 2021 (revision 71). I've pinged the SO mod who edited that in to see if they can give more context as to since when it's existed.

Is there a relevant Meta SE post for this change?

@gparyani It's been possible for moderators to undelete any comment since at least when I first became a moderator on SO in 2020. It's far from new. There's at least one reference to SO Mods viewing deleted comments on the page from which it's currently possible to undelete any comment from back in July of 2012. So, I suspect that the capability for moderators to undelete any comment has existed since at least that point.

@galacticninja This ability was requested in 2013, 2014, 2019, but see this discussion from 2021 (which I totally forgot I'd contributed to). So the change (if indeed there was a change) probably happened some time between 2019 and 2020 when Makyen was elected.

@Makyen "at least one reference to SO Mods viewing deleted comments on the page from which it's currently possible to undelete any comment" - but any reference to them being able to undelete comments from that page? I know that page has existed for as long as I've been a mod (2016), but I seem to recall the ability to undelete comments from it being added relatively recently. Can't find a post announcing that change on Meta.SE or the mod Team though ... going to check TL now.

@Randal'Thor BTW: if you want it to be a bit easier for you to undelete such comments, you might want to use Sam's "Comment Undeleter" userscript (GitHub; install), which, for moderators, adds a "undelete" button to all deleted comments on question pages and on the moderator flag handling pages.

Unfortunately, I can't think of any solution that doesn't require a lot of work (especially from mods). Some ideas:

If you know of any serial "well-meaning flaggers" as a mod it might be helpful to see what you can find in their flagging history.

With regular search, you can narrow down the questions this might have affected to about 9,000. With SEDE, someone could write a query to further narrow down the ones where the author's LastAccessDate is after an answer was posted. Only mods can detect deleted comments, however.


All things considered, it might be a good idea (as a policy) to edit the confirmation into the answer if it's only given as a comment (or non-answer) by an OP that's likely vanished instead of trying to save comments that can just as easily be deleted again. Thoughts?
